# How to estimate CSS text file size reduction when compressing with gziped

Tags: macos, gzip

I'm writing a Mac app to analyse CSS files and estimate size reduction when minified. I would also like to estimate the reduction in size obtained by the http compression using gzip. How can I do that? Is there any library that can help me?

Comment: "Estimate"? Just gzip it and compare the difference. [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) implements gz compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are better off simply doing the minification and gzipping and just presenting the difference. The time to actually do the work is not significant enough to estimate it by some other means. Even if you are analyzing 1000s of files at once, the user will likely have an expectation that the operation will take a bit of time to complete.